# How do I create a groups OS X Mavericks Contacts app that remains local to my machine?

Tags: macos, contacts

When creating a new group in the OS X Mavericks version of the Contacts apps the group is automatically synchronized to iCloud. I'd like to keep this group local to just the machine where I created it.

How can I make a group that stays local to the machine and does not sync to my iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **Contacts**
2. For the **On My Mac** account, click the **+** button to add a new group.

   [image]
3. Enter a group name and press **Enter**.

   [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can’t. Mavericks removes SyncServices for local syncing and forces you to place your data in the cloud.